# Import & transpose data - switch records from columns to rows (transpose not melt/cast)

Tags: r, import, analysis, transpose

I'm almost sure that this questions has been asked and answered, but I'm not really sure how to ask it, so here it goes:
I've got data that looks like this (there's about 1000 more that look like it):

```
    KV2c    KV2c    KV2c    I210plus    I210plus    I210plus    I210plus
    12s     16s     16s       1s          2s           2s          4s
    320     200     320      100         200          320          20


     T       T       F        F            T          T            T
```

If you notice, the top 4 rows have 4 characteristics of each unit that I'm observing...I want to import this into R as a dataframe and then look at the number of pass/fails (T's and F's) based on the various ways to permutate the 4 top rows.

For instance, maybe we'd like to address all units that are KV2c's that also are 12S and have a 200 in the 3rd row and, I don't know...get the percentage of T's vs. F's.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data needs some row headers as well as column headers to identify the characteristic for each row.  Alternatively add a column at the start to define the characteristic.  Then you will find the `melt` function useful as this will transform the data from wide format to long format.  Once it is in long format you have flexibility for plotting (`ggplot2` package) and aggregation/summarisation (`reshape2` package).  But start with a `melt` in my opinion...

Comment: Ok, I've melted it and it looks like it's much more willing to be worked with at least.  Would the next step to be to change the variable type of all items in the first couple rows to 'factor'?

Comment: The first couple of rows?When you melt the current column headings will become a new column in their own right and that should become a factor.  Perhaps you can paste the first few rows of the molten data.frame in R.  If the column names contain some form of logic or hierarchy (e.g. KV2c could be split into KV2 and c) then do that but let's assume it doesn't.  Perhaps remove the "s" from 12s, 1s characteristic to make it numeric if that's sensible too.  Unsure at this point why you would have the KV2c column repeated 3 times.

Comment: It would be very useful to see a fuller picture of the data.  It may be that because the first 4 rows combine to make the unique identifier you would need to first TRANSPOSE the data from columns to rows.

Comment: Hi Matt,  Thanks for the response.  The data is KV2c, I210plus, 4s, 320, etc (basically everything in the first 3 rows) are name data.  Each column represents an item that has those three characteristics...for instance, the first column describes a unit that is a KV2c type, in a 12s form, with a 320 rating.  They're just permutations of the 3 characteristics that can change in any given unit.  The big idea here is that I have a matrix of thousands of these units (all with their own specific construction which is described by the first 3 rows) and whether they passed or failed some tests.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is import this in R and be able to do things like "How many KV2c's failed such-and-such test", or "How many KV2c's with form 9s failed such-and-such test?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example which contains all of the elements you need to consider.  Try running this before linking to your own file.  The important step is converting `df` to `dft` using the `t()` function which transposes rows into columns.

Note that I've included a reference to the `reshape2` library for reformatting your data, there are many analysis alternatives out there.  This should get you started, obviously you would need to change the file name and column names when you link to your data.

```
# to generate a reproducible dataset
test.df = data.frame(
    expand.grid(ch1 = letters[1:3], ch2 = letters[1:3], ch3 = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    test.result = as.character(sample(c("T", "F"), 27, replace = TRUE)))
write.table(t(test.df), file = "testfile.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

# now to import the dataset into R
rm(list=ls())
df = read.csv("testfile.csv", header=FALSE)

# transpose your dataset to switch rows and columns and give meaningful names
dft = data.frame(t(df))
names(dft) = c("ch1", "ch2", "ch3", "test.result")
dft$test.result = ifelse(dft$test.result == "T", 1, 0) 

# the data is now in a format to perform analysis and plotting
library(reshape2)
dcast(dft, ch1 + ch2 ~ test.result)
with(dft, table(ch1, test.result, ch2))
```

As an after-thought, you quite probably want to convert the characteristics from data type `character` to `factor` prior to analysis.  This helps with plotting if you choose to use the excellent `ggplot2` package.  Here is an example to change one of the characteristics to a `factor`:

```
dft$ch1 = factor(dft$ch1)
```

A couple of useful sites for the basics of analysis & plotting that you need include:

http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Comment: Oh, yes!  This is very helpful!  Thank you very much.  Could you comment on if, instead of results for one test, the matrix included test results for multiple tests?  In other words, the ch1-ch3 would remain the same, but could we add functionality with this approach to accomodate not one row of T's and F's, but multiple rows of T's and F's?  Again, thank you very much for the coded example...Like working on cars or soldering wires, I believe learning by example is the best way to learn anything.  *high five*

Comment: Indeed it would work, you're just transposing the data.  However, if there is more than one measured variable or test (i.e. more than one value column to go with the 3 factor/descriptor columns) then you would possibly want to use `melt` so the variable name would form another column.  All depends on your analysis.  
I hope this solution is good enough to accept the answer to the original question - you can always create an additional question to resolve further specific issues.  Good luck.